# Add property dynamically to Linq's GroupBy result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, razor

I have two classes, `Customer` and `KPI`:

```
public class Customer : BaseModel
{
    public String Code { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<KPI> KPIs { get; set; }
}

public class KPI : BaseModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int PersonalValue { get; set; }
    public int RegionalValue { get; set; }
    public int NationalValue { get; set; }
    public String Group { get; set; }
}
```

I need to group KPI's by the `Group` property, so that if my data looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
| Name PValue RValue NValue Group |
+---------------------------------+
| Low    100    600    300    Car  |
| High   900    400    700    Car  |
| Low    200    300    500   Truck |
| High   800    700    500   Truck |
+---------------------------------+
```

After grouping the items, I'll need to have a few extra properties:

`Names: 'Low, High'` 
`PValuePercentages: '10, 90'`
`RValuePercentages: '60, 40'`
`NValuePercentages: '30, 70'`

This will basically be comma-separated strings with calculated values from the grouped items. I need them to be formatted like that so that I can easily plug them into HTML elements using Razor.

Here's exactly what I'm doing at the moment in Razor but in a .cs file for simpler testing and debugging:

```
foreach (var customer in customerList)
{
    var groups = customer.KPIs.GroupBy(item => item.Group);

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var groupName = group.Key ?? "OTHERS";

        foreach (var kpi in group)
        {
            var kpiName = kpi.Name;
            var personalValue = kpi.PersonalValue;
            var regionalValue = kpi.RegionalValue;
            var nationalValue = kpi.NationalValue;
        }

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Key))
        {
            // This doesn't work yet
            //var acuVal1 = group.AcuVal1;
            //var acuVal2 = group.AcuVal2;
            //var acuVal3 = group.AcuVal3;


            foreach (var kpi in group)
            {
                var kpiName= kpi.Name;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try changing the group by Linq query to

```
var groups = customer.KPIs.GroupBy(item => item.Group).
                    Select(item => new
                    {
                        item.Key,
                        item,
                        AcuVal1 = item.Sum(i => i.PersonalValue),
                        AcuVal2 = item.Sum(i => i.RegionalValue),
                        AcuVal3 = item.Sum(i => i.NationalValue)
                    }).ToList();
```

Note: `Sum()` is not what I need in this case but for testing purposes it works and keeps it simple.

After doing this, the lines

`foreach (var kpi in grupo)`

give the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '< anonymous
>   type: string Key, IGrouping item, int AcuVal1, int
>   AcuVal2, int AcuVal3>' because '< anonymous type: string Key,
>   IGrouping item, int AcuVal1, int AcuVal2, int AcuVal3>'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mjwills I figured I had already done that when I showed specific values for sample data, and how my grouped items should be calculated based on them. What else could I add to the question that makes it clearer?

Comment: I think the question should be more in the lines of: did I explain my issue clearly and gave specific examples that help understand what I'm trying to accomplish? I think I did. No, you can't copy and paste my code snippets into an IDE and work on them, but you can't do that for most questions on the Stack. I do believe you can easily understand what my problem is and if in possession of the knowledge (which I do not have, thus asking here), help me solve it.

Comment: `GroupBy` gives you the elements of each group (along with the key). All you need is to `Select` the desired information into anonymous type.

Comment: May be the right solution is to use a DataTable.  See : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Working-with-DataSets-and-DataTables-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor.aspx

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated the question with a hopefully better explanation of my problem with code. I've tried doing what you say, but can't get it to work.

Comment: @Antrim - What is the type of groups from your LINQ query with `Select`?

Answer (score 0):

when you `group by` into *item*, the *item* is an `IGrouping` of key value, while the *groups* is just a collection of an anonymous type having a *key* property and some aggregate properties and an *item* property.

given all this, if you want to iterate the sub collection of one grouping you need to iterate the *.item* property of a group

```
var groups = from kpi in kpis
            group kpi by kpi.Group into item
            select new
            {
                item.Key,
                item,
                AcuVal1 = item.Sum(i => i.PersonalValue),
                AcuVal2 = item.Sum(i => i.RegionalValue),
                AcuVal3 = item.Sum(i => i.NationalValue)
            };

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    foreach (var kpi in group.item)
    {
        var kpiName = kpi.Name;
    }
}
```

Note: I am pretty sure you don't actually need the nested foreach and that you should be able to achieve your desired outcome expanding on the group by results query

```
var groups = from kpi in kpis
            group kpi by kpi.Group into groupings
            let names = groupings.Select(p => p.Name)
            let pvalues = groupings.Select(p => p.PersonalValue)
            let rvalues = groupings.Select(p => p.RegionalValue)
            let nvalues = groupings.Select(p => p.NationalValue)
            select new
            {
                Key = groupings.Key,
                Names = string.Join(", ", names),
                PValues = string.Join(", ", pvalues),
                RValues = string.Join(", ", rvalues),
                NValues = string.Join(", ", nvalues),
            };
```

[image: outcome]